# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have my database named bookedscheduler and when I was to import an sql file an error like this occurs.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bookedscheduler`.`group_roles`, CONSTRAINT `group_roles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`role_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

---

Here's my code for the table 'roles' part:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `roles`;
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
 `role_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(85),
 `role_level` tinyint(2) unsigned,
 PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Here's the code for table 'user_roles':

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `group_roles`;
CREATE TABLE `group_roles` (
 `group_id` smallint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `role_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `role_id`),
 INDEX (`group_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES groups(`group_id`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 INDEX (`role_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`)
    REFERENCES roles(`role_id`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Is the .sql file inserting roles before inserting group_roles?

Comment: Do you understand what is a foreign key constraint? It blocks you from inserting data that violates that constraint. So either remove the constraint or insert proper data.